# Using fonts in Jinja2 template?

Tags: css, flask, jinja2, google-font-api

I am trying to add a google-font to my jinja2 template. I downloaded the google font and put it in the project directory, using this

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="{{ url_for('static', filename='fonts/Oswald-Bold.ttf')}}">
```

i tried to use the font in the template but it is not working. What is the proper way of doing this? The CSS looks like this

```
body {
  background-color: #ED9121;
  font-family: 'Oswald';
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

If I use the font directly from google instead of from my server, it works fine. Please help.

Comment: What's the structure of your static folder?

Comment: This- /home/xyz/project/blog/static/fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this in your CSS

```
@font-face {
        font-family: Oswald;
        src: url(/static/fonts/Oswald-Bold.ttf);
    }

body {
        font-family:Oswald;
    }
```

remove href="{{ url_for('static', filename='fonts/Oswald-Bold.ttf')}}"

also make sure your font is inside the folder fonts.
I tried it and for me this is working.

Comment: It works if i change the URL to src: url(/static/fonts/Oswald-Bold.ttf)

Comment: And now you're limited to TTF. This is not X-Browser-compatible, every browser requires a different font format: SVG, TTF, WOFF, WOFF2, EOT. Google fonts is generating a different CSS file based on the user agent requesting.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.localfont.com/ - you can download all font variants from there and it generates a X-Browser compatible CSS rule.

Answer (score 0):

We can change the font size by using the font tag and customizing the size

for example :

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
   <p><font size="6">Font size is 6</font></p>
   <p><font size="24">Font size is 24</font></p>
 </body>
</html>
```